# Format of entropy coded data for multiple channels in JPEG

Tags: jpeg, file-format

I'm trying to decode a JPEG file for the fun of it, and so far I've managed to get most of the important data out (Quantization tables, Huffman tables, Image Information). But I'm stuck at the entropy coded section that follows the SOS marker. There is a similar question here that I have seen [Parsing JPEG file format: Format of entropy-coded segments (ECS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467137/parsing-jpeg-file-format-format-of-entropy-coded-segments-ecs), and I understand that the bytes immediately after the SOS header is the JPEG data itself.

I understand the format of the SOS header, and it goes something like this

```
FF DA // SOS header
00 0A // Header length
03 // 3 channels
01 00 02 11 03 11 // channel 1 QT 0 HT 0, channel 2&3 QT 1 HT 1
00 3F 00 // Other important stuff
XX XX XX XX XX XX XX ... // Huffman-compressed MCU raw data
...
FF D9 // EOI
```

Now what I don't really understand is the huffman-compressed MCU raw data part. Firstly, I'm confused as to why there are two huffman tables. Secondly, how do I get the data from the multiple channels? Is it in the order of Y Cb Cr? Or YYYY...YYY CbCb....CbCb CrCr...CrCr?

I have looked at the source code of some JPEG decoders but they are really hard to read. I don't need this to be efficient, I just want to be able to eventually recreate the image.

Answer (score 0):

The format of the compressed data is complex and depends upon the type of SOF market.

There can be any number of huffman tables. Usually it's two (for Y and the other for Cb and Cr) or 3 (for each component).

Depending upon the scan structure, a scan can contain 1 component or all components (interleaved scan).

Comment: So for the particular file I'm working on, it happens to have 2 huffman trees. How do I figure out the structure of the scan structure? Is it in one of the other headers that I missed? I am primarily using this page to understand the file structure. http://vip.sugovica.hu/Sardi/kepnezo/JPEG%20File%20Layout%20and%20Format.htm, but I can't find any details in the headers on the entropy data.

Comment: I used this book to figure it out https://www.amazon.com/Compressed-Image-File-Formats-JPEG/dp/0201604434/